# .htaccess file cant be read on 9999 but working on 8080

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do something in .htaccess file but before doing it i am facing some problem and i have no clue about it

first of all my UAT server's html pages can be accessed through

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9999/cms

and in 9999 it is hosted in apache-tomcat

and htaccess file code :

```
RewriteEngine on
dadada
```

but its not throwing 500 internal server error it means it cant read .htaccess file

**BUT**

but in 8080 is only in apache2.2

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/cms/

in port 8080 it is mapped to /var/www/html/ so i place my html file here with .htaccess file and wooohhhaa it was working on 8080 with 500 server error but it when i deleted .htaccess file and just browse ny index page it says

```
"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /cms/ on this server."
```

now i have two questions.

Why htaccess is not running on port 9999 but on 8080?
and whats wrong with the permissions on 8080?

Comment: Error 500 doesn't mean that it can't read `.htaccess`, it just mean there's an error and you need to check the logs to learn about it because Apache won't display errors to the world. In any case, just compare the virtual host definitions for both sites and see what's different.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález error 500 mean it CAN read htaccess beacuse of the code it is throwing 500 but this is not the concern.